# React child element re-render on parent component resize (due to window resize)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, airtable

This is my first React project and I'm struggling with getting a component to resize after the window is resized. For this project I am creating a custom extension in Airtable. I am unsure if I have the right understanding of the parent/child relationship here. But anyway, this works perfectly for when the app initially renders, the child component is the same size as the parent component. However, when I resize the window, the parent component adjust along with everything else, but the child component does not change when the parent component changes.

```
export default function ThisIsAReactComponent(props) {
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refContainer.current) {
      setDimensions({
        width: refContainer.current.offsetWidth,
        height: refContainer.current.offsetHeight,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ThisIsAChildComponent
        table={props.table}
        height={dimensions.height ? dimensions.height - 10 : "100%"}
      />

      <Box ref={refContainer} width="100%" height="100%">
        <ThisIsTheParentComponent
          datas={aFunction(props.table)[0].Data}
          records={aFunction(props.table)[0].Records}
          heading={"A Heading"}
          pad={2}
          table={props.table}
        />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried making the height a key in the child component but it still doesn't make it re-render. I have been trying to find a solution, but so far have been unable to get it to work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i think you are trying to control the child height with states, in this case when the window height changes, you need to change the state as well, add an event listener to window for resize and in the callback call setDimensions again